# IDA Pro Flow Chart and Decompiler Doesn't Work on Single Instruction text

Tags: ida, decompilation

Recently I got a program that has two colors of `.text` segment, one is `black` and the other is `brown`:

[image]

While the flow chart and the decompiler work well on `black` part, they are both disabled on the `brown` part, as below:

[image]

Later, I found the `brown` `.text` part is categorized as `Single instruction`, rather than `Regular function`:

[image]

I wonder if there is a way, to make the Flow Chart and the Decompiler work for the `Single instruction` part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The brown text is called as single instruction because the function, prologue of which we see in brown color, was not recognized by IDA as function.

There are many possible reasons for that, for example this function may be never called directly, or there is unrecognized instruction inside. In order to make this code a function (which will make it black) by defining it as a function yourself, you can press <kbd>P</kbd> when the cursor is located on address `0x00405fd0` where the function prologue starts, or select all the functions' instructions and press <kbd>P</kbd>.

When this code becomes function, the graphs and decompilation should start working.